# I can't install WebDriverAgentRunner. 'CocoaAsyncSocket / GCDAsyncSocket.h' file not found

Tags: ios, xcode, appium

I'm having a problem installing WebDriverAgentRunner on iPhone X running iOS 14.2.

I am trying to install WebDriverAgentRunner on iPhone X running iOS 14.0 via XCode 12.2 but during the build I get the error: 'CocoaAsyncSocket / GCDAsyncSocket.h' file not found

Until the version installed on my iPhone X was iOS 13.x I was able to install the WebDriverAgentRunner. After updating to iOS 14.0 I am no longer able to install it.

How can I import 'CocoaAsyncSocket / GCDAsyncSocket.h'?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Make sure **Carthage** binary is up to the latest one, cleanup the leftovers before you download dependencies:

```
rm -rf ~/Library/Caches/org.carthage.CarthageKit
brew upgrade carthage
```

After you did it, I suggest re-build WebdriverAgent

```
carthage bootstrap --no-use-binaries
cp Cartfile.resolved Carthage
./Scripts./bootstrap.sh -d
```

If it still won't work, you can try [this](https://github.com/appium/appium/issues/13687#issuecomment-655067739)